# How Controller convert JSON data from AJAX to Model instance?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

Just out of curiosity. I observed that when I make POST method in AJAX. I always mention `datatype:'json'` and it actually works with my model instance in parameter in Controller - The URL path  mentioned in AJAX. But, at the same time when I was sending data to JQGrid I needed JSON return type controller to send data in JSON format.

How could model type method can auto-adjust itself with JSON format data?

Answer (score 0):

**For Using jqGrid With ASP.NET MVC**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Model

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
   
}
```

Ajax Example

```
var model = { Id :12, Text :"Testing Data"};
 $ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     url:'/ExampleController/ExMethod',
     data:{'exampleModel' : model},
     success: (result) =>{
         console.log(result);
     },
     error : (error) =>{
         console.log(error);
     }
 }}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string ExMethod(ExampleModel exampleModel){
     return null;
}
```

Comment: I am asking, how this ```dataType:Json``` is being set in ExampleModel instance? Thanks!